# Boton cerrar en windowsForm - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola amigos esto es lo que quiero hacer:

- Programar el botón cerrar que trae por defecto windowsform y que al hacer clic me cierre este y me habra otra.

eh buscado algo de usar formCLosing pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.
podrian ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo estás haciendo con VS, selecciona el formulario, clic derecho, propiedades, vas a eventos y doble clic sobre FormClosing. Esto creará los bindings, y el método de ese EventListener.

Este sería el código dentro del método Formulario1_FormClosing:

```
e.Cancel = true;
Hide();
new Formulario2().Show();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo